# Why X11 automatically shutdown during a calculation?

Tags: x11

I was using X11 to calculate crystallization of a primitive magma. The calculation went well in small increments. But when I launch bigger calculations in wider T ranges, X11 shutdown automatically with no reason.

Comment: Melts-rhyolite-public(3599,0x7fff757c2300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd7d1c87dc0: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm not sure how you were using a windowing system to calculate crystallization of anything. Please provide more detail of what it is you were doing, what you expected to happen, and what actually happens along with any error messages.